# Memory Leak Issue in function similar to scanf

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

In the Code below I am trying to recreate `scanf` to read everything from the `stdin` and break on the new line character returning all the characters read in a string.

But the problem is that the code leaks some memory especially when `realloc` gets invoked.

I would also like to know why is `gets` a dangerous function to use

`test.c: warning: the 'gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.`

My Code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_BUF_LEN 128
#define __cdecl

//0 - Success
//-1 - Error in input
//1 - Error
__cdecl int read_input(char *s,int len){

char c,*t;
int l,i=0;

if(s==NULL || len < 1)
    return -1;

while((c=getchar()) != '\n'){

    //check if sufficient memory
    //required + used > assigned 
    l=strlen(s);
    if(l + 2 > len){

        len += l + MAX_BUF_LEN;     //realloc max to avoid subsequent realloc as its costly!

        t = realloc(s,len);
        if(t!=NULL)
            s = t;
        else
            return 1;               //No space to store content
    }

    s[i++] = c;

}

s[i++] = '\0';      //Null terminate the Buffer
return 0;   
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

int len = 5+1;
char *s = calloc(len,sizeof(char));

printf("Enter your name\n");

if(!read_input(s,len))
    printf("Hi %s\n",s);

free(s);

return 0;
}
```

Valgrind :

```
nimish:~/Desktop$ gcc -g -Wall test.c -o test
nimish~/Desktop$ clear && valgrind ./test  --leak-check=full

==3670== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3670== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3670== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3670== Command: ./test --leak-check=full
==3670== 
Enter your name
Nimish Nicolus
==3670== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3670==    at 0x4027029: strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:282)
==3670==    by 0x804850E: read_input (test.c:23)
==3670==    by 0x80485CD: main (test.c:51)
==3670== 
==3670== Invalid read of size 1
==3670==    at 0x40831BF: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1623)
==3670==    by 0x40891BF: printf (printf.c:35)
==3670==    by 0x80485E6: main (test.c:52)
==3670==  Address 0x41a5028 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 6 free'd
==3670==    at 0x402695A: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==3670==    by 0x8048537: read_input (test.c:28)
==3670==    by 0x80485CD: main (test.c:51)
==3670== 
==3670== Invalid read of size 1
==3670==    at 0x40A93A8: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.1 (fileops.c:1317)
==3670==    by 0x408346F: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1623)
==3670==    by 0x40891BF: printf (printf.c:35)
==3670==    by 0x80485E6: main (test.c:52)
==3670==  Address 0x41a502c is 4 bytes inside a block of size 6 free'd
==3670==    at 0x402695A: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==3670==    by 0x8048537: read_input (test.c:28)
==3670==    by 0x80485CD: main (test.c:51)
==3670== 
==3670== Invalid read of size 1
==3670==    at 0x40A93BF: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.1 (fileops.c:1317)
==3670==    by 0x408346F: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1623)
==3670==    by 0x40891BF: printf (printf.c:35)
==3670==    by 0x80485E6: main (test.c:52)
==3670==  Address 0x41a502b is 3 bytes inside a block of size 6 free'd
==3670==    at 0x402695A: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==3670==    by 0x8048537: read_input (test.c:28)
==3670==    by 0x80485CD: main (test.c:51)
==3670== 
==3670== Invalid read of size 1
==3670==    at 0x40A9330: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.1 (fileops.c:1349)
==3670==    by 0x408346F: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1623)
==3670==    by 0x40891BF: printf (printf.c:35)
==3670==    by 0x80485E6: main (test.c:52)
==3670==  Address 0x41a5028 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 6 free'd
==3670==    at 0x402695A: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==3670==    by 0x8048537: read_input (test.c:28)
==3670==    by 0x80485CD: main (test.c:51)
==3670== 
==3670== Invalid read of size 1
==3670==    at 0x40A933C: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.1 (fileops.c:1348)
==3670==    by 0x408346F: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1623)
==3670==    by 0x40891BF: printf (printf.c:35)
==3670==    by 0x80485E6: main (test.c:52)
==3670==  Address 0x41a502a is 2 bytes inside a block of size 6 free'd
==3670==    at 0x402695A: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==3670==    by 0x8048537: read_input (test.c:28)
==3670==    by 0x80485CD: main (test.c:51)
==3670== 
Hi Nimis
==3670== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==3670==    at 0x4025BF0: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
==3670==    by 0x80485F2: main (test.c:54)
==3670==  Address 0x41a5028 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 6 free'd
==3670==    at 0x402695A: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==3670==    by 0x8048537: read_input (test.c:28)
==3670==    by 0x80485CD: main (test.c:51)
==3670== 
==3670== 
==3670== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3670==     in use at exit: 139 bytes in 1 blocks
==3670==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 145 bytes allocated
==3670== 
==3670== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3670==    definitely lost: 139 bytes in 1 blocks
==3670==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3670==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3670==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3670==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3670== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3670== 
==3670== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3670== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==3670== ERROR SUMMARY: 23 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)
```

EDIT :- PLEASE REFER TO THE NEW CODE ATTACHED BELOW

New Code :-

```
__cdecl int read_input(char **s,int len){

char c,*t;
int l,i=0;

if((*s)==NULL || len < 1)
    return -1;

while((c=getchar()) != '\n'){

    //check if sufficient memory
    //required + used > assigned 
    l=strlen((*s));
    if(l + 2 > len){

        len += l + MAX_BUF_LEN;     //realloc max to avoid subsequent realloc as its costly!

        t = realloc((*s),len);
        if(t!=NULL)
            (*s) = t;
        else
            return 1;               //No space to store content
    }

    *((*s)+i++) = c;

}

*((*s)+i) = '\0';       //Null terminate the Buffer
return 0;   
}
```

Valgrind :

```
==4767== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4767== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4767== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4767== Command: ./test --leak-check=full
==4767== 
Enter your name
Nimish Nicolus
==4767== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4767==    at 0x4027029: strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:282)
==4767==    by 0x8048516: read_input (test.c:23)
==4767==    by 0x80485DE: main (test.c:51)
==4767== 
Hi Nimish Nicolus
==4767== 
==4767== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4767==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4767==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 145 bytes allocated
==4767== 
==4767== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4767== 
==4767== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4767== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==4767== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)
```

It still gives some issue.

Comment: well, that may not be the question but it seems you're replacing last character of your string by `\0`. Don't misuse `i++` for `++i` or `i+1`.

Comment: `s[i++] = '\0';      //Null terminate the Buffer` should be `s[i] = '\0';      //Null terminate the Buffer` because the i gets incremented in while itself so the array is null terminated. i no longer gets used so avoiding the extra increment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gets) has to say about `gets` problem:

> Never use gets(). Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use. It has been used to break computer security. Use fgets() instead.

The leak problem happens because the pointer `s` is passed by value, so any changes, including assignments after reallocation, are done to its *copy*, not to the original pointer. As a consequence, freeing `s` frees only the memory that has been allocated originally, leaking the `realloc`-ed one. To fix this, change `read_input` to take a pointer to a pointer, like this:

```
int read_input(char **ps,int len)
```

Pass `&s` to `read_input`, and use `(*ps)` in place of `s` in the body of the function.

Comment: I am understanding what you mean. due to `realloc` the memory location could change as suggested by @Judge Maygarden and this will create a problem for `free`. But if i was not using `Realloc` I think this code would work flawlessly. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 3):

Your not returning the pointer to the allocated buffer. So, `free(s)` is not doing what you expect. `realloc` is not guaranteed to provide extra space at the same location. So, the buffer could move. A solution would be to pass a pointer-to-a-pointer or return the pointer instead of an `int` and use NULL to indicate an error.

PS - There are other issues and this is very unsafe code.

Answer (score 2):

In the loop, this you use:

```
l=strlen(s);
```

but `s` wasn't terminated with null anywhere within the loop. So subsequently when you call `strlen()` on that will not give you what you expect, which could be the reason for memory leak. So make sure you terminate the string with null within the loop.

`gets` is dangerous because it allows you read more than the space you allocated for.

Comment: `calloc` zero initializes the memory block so `strlen` will not face a problem I guess

Comment: That's right. I thought it's malloc and that's not the case. Does it work now?

Comment: Not really there is still some issue with `strlen` i will post a new answer with the `valgrind` result and what changes I did in the code.

Answer (score 2):

gets() is dangerous because it has no information how large your buffer actually is, hence it cannot prevent buffer overrun on large input line. For bad guys, the buffer overrun is one very common attack vector. Use fgets() with stdin as first parameter instead, which allow you to specify how large the buffer is.